# Ubuntu 16.04 does not find any printer

Tags: printing, 16.04

Before switching from Ubuntu 15.10 to Ubuntu 16.04 all three connected printers were working. They still work with the parallel installed Mint 17.

Is there a way to get them work again under Ubuntu 16.04? Which additional information do I have to post?

Comment: Do the printers still show up in the printers control panel? I didn't have these problems with 16.04, but when printers stopped working after an upgrade, deleting them from the control panel and reinstalling them was working every time and the easiest and fastest way.

Comment: No printer is showing up.

Comment: Maybe you chose the default settings during the  upgrade instead of keeping yours. Just reinstalling the printers should be fine.

Comment: How can I reinstall them, if Ubuntu does nor find any of them?

Comment: What do you mean? Are they not discovered by 'add new printer'? What is `systemctl status cups` showing?

Comment: ulrich@ASRock:~$ systemctl status cups
● cups.service - CUPS Scheduler
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cups.service; enabled; vendor preset: ena
   Active: active (running) since Mo 2016-05-09 23:01:09 CEST; 4min 9s ago
     Docs: man:cupsd(8)
 Main PID: 2549 (cupsd)
    Tasks: 4 (limit: 512)
   CGroup: /system.slice/cups.service
           ├─2549 /usr/sbin/cupsd -l
           ├─2551 /usr/lib/cups/notifier/dbus dbus:// 
           ├─2552 /usr/lib/cups/notifier/dbus dbus:// 
           └─2553 /usr/lib/cups/notifier/dbus dbus://

Comment: Your cups seems to be running alright. What's about forcing it by adding a printer? Click on 'network printers' after 'add new printer', assuming this is what we are talking about.

Comment: Also no network printer shows up. Host: fritz.box   Port:9100 is answered by "CUPS server error" There was an error during CUPS operation: 'server-error-internal-error'.

Comment: I have also connected two printers directly via USB, none of them shows up.

Comment: I have reinstalled Ubuntu 16.04. Now all three printers show up again. I'll install all other programs, which I hat installed succesively and if the error shows up again, I'll let you know.       Thanks for trying to help me.

Comment: It most probably works from the fresh start. Next time, getting rid of CUPS by `apt purge cups cups-client cups-bsd` and also `apt purge hplip hpijs printer-driver-gutenprint` if needed and then reinstalling these packages by `apt install` instead of purge should get the job done as well. Also drastic, but at least not a complete reinstall.

Answer (score 3):

I followed @emk2203 suggestion and it worked.

**Fresh start**

*Purge*

```
sudo apt purge cups cups-client cups-bsd
sudo apt purge hplip hpijs printer-driver-gutenprint
```

*Install*

```
sudo apt install cups cups-client cups-bsd
sudo apt install hplip hpijs printer-driver-gutenprint
```

Then my printer could be found with `nmap`.

Comment: This appears to no longer work on Ubuntu 16-04. Instead, doing just the purges mentioned above followed by `sudo apt install printer-driver-hpijs` seemed to do the trick.

Comment: @Thor84no I had a fresh install and did not have any prior settings. Only your command worked for me. Thanks!